# Change GallerificPlus effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I'm searching how to combining galleriffic and lightbox jquery plugin until I found GallerifficPlus ([I have downloaded it here](http://www.mattgifford.co.uk/projects/gallerificplus)).

Is it possible (once deleted the slideshows) to call the lightbox by clicking on the thumbs? I want the lightbox function work after clicking the thumbnail..

Here's the code for the thumbnail part

```
        buildDataFromThumbs: function() {
            this.data = [];
            var gallery = this;
            this.$thumbsContainer.find('li').each(function(i) {
                var $a = $(this).find('a');
                var $img = $a.find('img:first');
                gallery.data.push({slide:$a.attr('href'),thumb:$img.attr('src'),original:$a.attr('original'),title:$a.attr('title'),description:$a.attr('description'),hash:gallery.offset+i});
            });
            return this;
        },
```

for the original display message

```
        buildImage: function(image) {
            if (this.$imageContainer) {
                this.$imageContainer.empty();

                var gallery = this;

                var thisImageIndex = this.currentIndex;

                // Setup image
                this.$imageContainer
                    //.append('<span class="image-wrapper"><a class="advance-link" rel="history" href="#'+this.data[this.getNextIndex(this.currentIndex)].hash+'" title="'+image.alt+'"></a></span>')
                    .append('<span class="image-wrapper"><a class="advance-link" rel="history" title="'+image.alt+'"></a></span>')
                    .find('a')
                    .append(image)
                    //.click(function() { clickHandler(gallery); })
                    .click(function() { buildLightBox(image,gallery,thisImageIndex); })
                    .end()
                    .fadeIn('fast');

                if (this.onFadeIn) this.onFadeIn();
            }
```

Also, are there any other jquery plugin you can suggest that has similar function?

Comment: I just checked that out. It occurs to me that this library is broken, at least for me. Even the example won't work properly.
If you click on the thumbs nothing is happening, except that the URL is changed. So I am not surprised that displaying the lightbox does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this could help but did you try [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) plugin. i think it works the way you want.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but that is not the one that i'm referring about.. :(